# ¿Cómo puedo sumar el valor de varias variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objeto

Quiero definir una variable total en donde poder calcular el importe total de monedas seleccionadas ya que cada valor representa una moneda diferente y después tendré que multiplicarlo ese valor para darme el total en €.

Este es el código:

```
introducir el código aquí


$(function () {

$("#calcula").click(function(){

         var c1 = document.getElementById("c1").value;
         var c2 = document.getElementById("c2").value;
         var c5 = document.getElementById("c5").value;
         var c10 = document.getElementById("c10").value;
         var c20 =document.getElementById("c20").value;
         var c50 = document.getElementById("c50").value; 
  });

         //var total = ;
        // alert(total);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido  @Azumay404 lo que debes hacer es agregar la operación dentro del evento click ademan incializar tu variable total en 0.

ejemplo:

```
    $(function () {
           var total = 0;
           $("#calcula").click(function(){

                 var c1 = document.getElementById("c1").value;
                 var c2 = document.getElementById("c2").value;
                 var c5 = document.getElementById("c5").value;
                 var c10 = document.getElementById("c10").value;
                 var c20 =document.getElementById("c20").value;
                 var c50 = document.getElementById("c50").value; 
                //aqui puedes hacer la conversión a cada moneda
                 total = parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(c2)+parseFloat(c5)+parseFloat(c10)+parseFloat(c20)+parseFloat(c50);

      alert(total);
           });        

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan Carlos, me sirvió de gran ayuda el total